# Matching lisboxes items and creating result

Tags: c#, comparison, listboxitem

I am creating an Exam system in c#. I am creating result, i have answers in a listbox1 and correct answers in another listbox2, my issue is values in the listboxes should be compared and result should be generated on its base. If half the values match student is pass otherwise fail.
My code for this is following but it does not work.

```
for(int intCount = 0; intCount < listBoxSanswers.Items.Count;intCount++)
{
    for (int intSubCount = 0; intSubCount < listBoxActAnswers.Items.Count; intSubCount++)
    {
        if (listBoxActAnswers.Items[intCount].ToString() == listBoxActAnswers.Items[intSubCount].ToString())
        {     
            listBox3.Items.Add(listBoxActAnswers.Items[intCount].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your if statement one of the two lists should be "listBoxSanswers"

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work" what do you mean exactly? Is an error being thrown or are you not getting the results you expected?

Comment: Does not work means it does not copy the common items of two listboxes in third listbox. I want items of listbox1 and listbox2 should be compared and common items should be added to listbox3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your approach, than you have to change one of the two lists to `listBoxSanswers`

If you want a shorter way, without the loops, you can try this line:

```
listBox3.Items.AddRange(listBoxActAnswers.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().Intersect(listBoxSanswers.Items.Cast<string>().ToList()).ToArray());
```

**EDIT:**
Oh okay, so you have a DataTable as a DataSource.
Than you can do it this way:

```
listBox3.Items.AddRange(listBoxActAnswers.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(r => r[0]).ToList().Intersect(listBoxSanswers.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(r => r[0]).ToList()).ToArray());
```

Maybe you should adapt `Select(r => r[0])` to the right column which is your DisplayMember.

Comment: your code throw following error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.String'.